# why I couln`t set bool in X variable as false?

Tags: typescript

Why can't I set `bool` in `x` variable to `false`?

Isn't `{bool: Boolean}` the same with `{bool: false\true}`?

How can I do it except creating new variable of Boolean type?

`

```
type Boolean = {
     done : boolean;
 }
type date = {
    name:string,
    bool : Boolean
}

 const p : Boolean = {done:false};
 const r : date = {name:'name', bool:p}
 const x : date = {name:'name', bool: false} // why i couln`t set bool as false ?
```

``

Comment: In `date` type  set `done: boolean` instead of `bool : Boolean` , and remove `Boolean ` type. Then, `const x : date = {name:'name', done: false}`

Comment: type 'Boolean' is not the same as type 'boolean'. Similarly, for completeness, type 'Number' is not the same as type 'number', and type 'String' is not the same as type 'string'. Always use the types that start with the lowercase letter (boolean, number, string etc), unless you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `type Boolean = {done: boolean}` shadows the global `Boolean` type, so the type `date` is the same as:

```
type date = {
    name: string
    bool: {done: boolean}
}
```

If you want both `r` and `x` (in your example) to work, you can use a union type:

```
type date = {
    name: string
    bool: Boolean | boolean
}
```

I recommend against shadowing global variables/types, as this can lead to confusion.